# VB .NET Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data Task - Class - Find BillingInformation & Mileage value from Email - Syntax

Tags: .net, vb.net, exchangewebservices

Gets error : The item type returned by the service (EmailMessage) isn't compatible with the requested item type (Task).

**I'm trying to find the value of :**

```
 Dim value As String
 Dim service1 As ExchangeService = New 
 ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013, easternZone)
 service1.Credentials = New WebCredentials(UserID, Password)
 service1.Url = New Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx") 

 Dim findResults As FindItemsResults(Of Item) = service1.FindItems(folderID1, unReadFilter, New ItemView(50))

 For Each item As Item In findResults
    Dim val = item.Id.ToString()
   mytask1 = Task.Bind(service1, val)
   value = mytask1.Mileage.ToString() Next
```

this is from an Email message through Exchange .WebServices. Data class . 
when we add values to Email attributes like 
"Millage " or "Billing information" - we can find these available .

I get the below  error :

```
-       ex  {"The item type returned by the service (EmailMessage) isn't compatible with the requested item type (Task)."}  System.Exception {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceLocalException}
```

I'm using the references from Microsoft docs to make the code :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.task?view=exchange-ews-api

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.task.billinginformation?view=exchange-ews-api#Microsoft_Exchange_WebServices_Data_Task_BillingInformation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.task.bind?view=exchange-ews-api

- Any help is extremely appreciated - I'm stuck from last couple of days .
- I'm a beginner to Exchange Service class . [error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs9wB.jpg)

Comment: I would suggest to set a breakpoint and verify the type of the items being returned. EmailMessage doesn't have BillingInformation or Mileage. You might need to add extra logic in your For loop to handle items differently based on the type.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply - Jazakari . - an update - I get the exception at line :      mytask1 = Task.Bind(service1, val)    - so I guess it do not go to finding the millage value - also I''m trying to find what all the item object has .

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the Extended properties definitions for those properties to do what you trying https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidlidbilling-canonical-property and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidlidmileage-canonical-property eg

```
 Dim PidLidBilling As new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Common, 0x8535,MapiPropertyType.String)
 Dim PidLidMileage As new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Common, 0x8534, MapiPropertyType.String)
 Dim psPropertySet As New PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties)
 psPropertySet.Add(PidLidMileage)
 psPropertySet.Add(PidLidBilling)

mytask1 = Task.Bind(service1, val,psPropertySet)
Dim mileageValue As [Object] = Nothing
If mytask1.TryGetProperty(PidLidMileage, mileageValue) Then
    Console.WriteLine(mileageValue)
End If
```

Comment: Hello Glen 
Thanks a lot for the efforts . 

I tried the above code - got an error as the Hex value cannot be accepted .
I tried to convert it to integer - that resolved the error
-BUT that again causes exception in  Task.Bind - stating the Service is not compatible.

Comment: Added the error screenshot below - Requesting to please guide . - Many Thanks in advance .

Comment: Sorry if its an Email you will still need to bind to it as an Email and then access the extended properties

Comment: Thanks a TON Glen - you are indeed an Unsung Hero :-) - I was able to get the info - Mileage and Billing Info -  was finishing the whole process - hence late to confirm here - :-) . ***Thanks again Mate ... Thanks a lot .***

Answer (score 0):

@ Glen please find the error screenshot below : 
[Gets Error when trying to use extended properties definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jlcok.jpg)